# R : Change name of variable using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, r-colnames

I have a data, and  vectors conatin name of variables, from these vectorsi calculate the sum of variables contained in the vector and i want to put the result in a new variables that have diffrent names

let say i have three vectors

```
>data

Name      A    B    C    D    E
r1        1    5    12  21    15
r2        2    4     7  10     9
r3        5   15     6   9     6
r4        7    8     0   7    18
```

And i have these vectors that are generated using for loop that are in variable vec

```
V1 <- ("A","B","C")
V2 <- ("B","D")
V3 <- ("D","E")
```

Edit 1 :
These vector are generated using for loop and i don't know the vectors that will be generated or the elemnts contained in these vector , here i'm giving just an example , i want to calculate the sum of variables in each vector and make the result in new variable in my data frame
The issue is don't know how to give new name to variables created (that contains the sum of each vector)

```
 data$column[j]  <- rowSums(all_data_Second_program[,vec])
 j <- j+1
```

To obtain this result for example

```
Name      A    B    C   Column1      D     Column2    E      Column3
 r1       1    5   12     18         21      26      15         36 
 r2       2    4    7     13         10      14       9         19
 r3       5   15    6     26          9      24       6         15
 r4       7    8    0     15          7      15      18         25
```

But i didn't obtain this result

Please tell me if you need any more informations or clarifications
Can you tell me please how to that

Answer (score 0):

Put the vectors in a list and then you can use `rowSums` in `lapply` -

```
list_vec <- list(c("A","B","C"), c("B","D"), c("D","E"))
new_cols <- paste0('Column', seq_along(list_vec))

data[new_cols] <- lapply(list_vec, function(x) rowSums(data[x]))
data

#  Name A  B  C  D  E Column1 Column2 Column3
#1   r1 1  5 12 21 15      18      26      36
#2   r2 2  4  7 10  9      13      14      19
#3   r3 5 15  6  9  6      26      24      15
#4   r4 7  8  0  7 18      15      15      25
```

Comment: The vectors are generated using for loop that's why i can't create list conatining the vectors so i generated and treated every vector inside the for loop is there's any way i can add each column alone ?

Comment: But you are doing `Vectors <- c(V1,V2,V3)`. What I am suggesting is to do `Vectors <- list(V1,V2,V3)` instead. I have used variable name as `list_vec` instead of `Vectors`.

Comment: I edited the questio  to describe more the problem, please see my question again

Answer (score 0):

We may use a `for` loop

```
for(i in 1:3) {
    data[[paste0('Column', i)]] <- rowSums(data[get(paste0('V', i))],
          na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

-output

```
> data
  Name A  B  C  D  E Column1 Column2 Column3
1   r1 1  5 12 21 15      18      26      36
2   r2 2  4  7 10  9      13      14      19
3   r3 5 15  6  9  6      26      24      15
4   r4 7  8  0  7 18      15      15      25
```